# Reiterate through array and add to DB - Laravel/Eloquent/PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having difficulties retrieving an `Eloquent` model and lopping through it and then adding it to another table.

So here is my query;

```
$cart = Cart::with('cartItems','cartItems.cartModifierItems')->where(['vcode' => $code, 'cookie_id' => $cookie])->first();
```

This retrieves the below;

```
[
  {
    "id": 14,
    "cookie_id": "2e5c22eba9ef7affe78b34e10d35f89dd5fbdd3b",
    "user_id": 3,
    "restaurant_id": 11,
    "restaurant_name": "Gaucho",
    "restaurant_uname": "gaucho",
    "location": "asokoro",
    "city": "abuja",
    "date": "2016-02-11",
    "time": "12:00:00",
    "vcode": "5960010",
    "created_at": "2016-02-09 13:57:34",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-13 02:29:56",
    "cart_items": [
      {
        "id": 88,
        "item_id": 159,
        "restaurant_id": 11,
        "cart_cookie": "2e5c22eba9ef7affe78b34e10d35f89dd5fbdd3b",
        "name": "Empanadas (Choice of 2)",
        "description": "Choice of Diced Beef; Spinach, Stilton and Onion; or Smoked Ham and Mozzarella",
        "price": 700,
        "qty": 5,
        "available": 1,
        "created_at": "2016-02-10 20:42:32",
        "updated_at": "2016-02-11 07:07:51",
        "cart_id": 14,
        "cart_modifier_items": [
          {
            "id": 76,
            "item_id": 34,
            "name": "Diced Beef",
            "price": 50,
            "created_at": "2016-02-10 20:42:32",
            "updated_at": "2016-02-10 20:42:32",
            "cart_item_id": 88,
            "cart_id": 14
          },
          {
            "id": 77,
            "item_id": 35,
            "name": "Smoked Salmon & Mozzarella",
            "price": 50,
            "created_at": "2016-02-10 20:42:32",
            "updated_at": "2016-02-10 20:42:32",
            "cart_item_id": 88,
            "cart_id": 14
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see there are 3 levels;

Top level is `cart`
Middle level is `cart_items`
Bottom level is `cart_modifier_items`

`cart` can contain multiple `cart_items`

`cart_items` can contain multiple `cart_modifier_items`

What I'm trying to do is take this output and copy it to identical tables;
The models are also identical

`order`, `order_items`, `order_item_modifiers`

Top level is `order`
Middle level is `order_items`
Bottom level is `order_item_modifiers`

`order` can contain multiple `order_items`

`order_items` can contain multiple `order_item_modifiers`

This is what I have done so far;

```
$order = Order::create([
    'order_id' => $order_number,
    'date' => $cart['date'],
    'time' => $cart['time'],
    'total' => $total,
    'subtotal' => $subtotal,
    'order_status_id' => 1,
    'customer_id' => $id,
    'restaurant_id' => $cart['restaurant_id'],
])->id;

if (!empty($cart['cart_items'])) {

    foreach($cart['cart_items'] as $order_item) {

        $orderItem = OrderItem::create([
            'item_id' => $order_item['id'],
            'name' => $order_item['name'],
            'description' => $order_item['description'],
            'price' => $order_item['price'],
            'qty' => $order_item['qty'],
            'restaurant_id' => $order_item['restaurant_id'],
            'order_id' => $order,
        ])->id;

        if (!empty($order_item['cart_modifier_items'])) {

            foreach ($order_item['cart_modifier_items'] as $order_modifier_item) {
                OrderItemModifier::create([
                    'item_id' => $order_modifier_item['id'],
                    'name' => $order_modifier_item['name'],
                    'price' => $order_modifier_item['price'],
                    'order_id' => $order,
                    'order_item_id' => $orderItem,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With my code all I get is the `order`. The `order_items` and `order_item_modifiers` don't get created in `DB`. I also don't get any errors from `laravel`

I'm definitely doing something wrong with my loop or how I access the inner arrays. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are your ``$fillable`` arrays containt mass-assignment fields?

Comment: @arma Yes all declared in my `models`

Comment: does your query actually returns arrays of objects or it's just your debug output? Looks like it should be ``$cart->id`` and ``$order_item->id`` and ``$order_modifier_item->id`` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `$cart['cart_items']` and `$order_item['cart_modifier_items']` don't actually exist, so your `!empty()` checks are returning `false`.

You're being tricked by a little bit of `Model` magic. When you dumped your `$cart` object to see what was in it, it calls a series of functions to convert your model into a json object. In the method called to dump the relationship data, it converts the relationship name from `camelCase` into `snake_case`, and adds that to the json object. So, even though your Model has a `cartItems` attribute, your json dump is going to show `cart_items`.

So, the quick fix is to change `$cart['cart_items']` to `$cart['cartItems']`, and `$order_item['cart_modifier_items']` to `$order_item['cartModifierItems']`.

---

A quick note: even though Laravel's `Model` implements `ArrayAccess`, which means you can access data like `$cart['date']`, `$cart['cartItems']`, etc., it is generally more acceptable to treat it as the object it is and access it's properties with the arrow syntax (`$cart->date`, `$cart->cartItems`, etc.).

Comment: Lol @ `magic`... Cheers mate. Very helpful! Sorted my issue thanks to your guidance.